# How to convert .odt to latex?

Tags: libreoffice, latex

What is the best software to convert .odt to latex?

Using Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**writer2latex** works with Ubuntu 16.04!

Installation:

`sudo apt-get install writer2latex writer2latex-manual`

How to use it: go to the target file directory and:

`w2l file.odt`

[writer2latex full documentation](http://writer2latex.sourceforge.net/doc1.4/user-manual-screen.pdf)

Comment: I think this should be `w2l file.odt` rather than `w2t file.odt`.